# Assign Order to Customer after new customer import

Tags: mysql, magento, orders

my website got hacked and all the customers were deleted, but the orders are still here.

I imported back the customers from a backup (via CSV) but the orders are no longer linked to them.

I need to know how I can assign orders to customers in the database. Is it possible to find a way to link them again using the email? Because the email still appears in the order information.

This query has linked the accounts to the orders, it means I can see the clients infos in the order page.

UPDATE sales_flat_order as SFO INNER JOIN customer_entity as C on C.email = SFO.customer_email SET SFO.customer_id = C.entity_id WHERE SFO.customer_is_guest = 0

But when I open clients accounts > Orders tab, the orders are not there.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this page on how to ask a good question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score -2):

If there there is foreign key from customer table in order table, then 
you can update this field with value from customer table where is same email in order and customer.

Something like this:

```
update Order_tab 
set Order_tab.CUS_ID=Customer_tab.CUS_ID
from Customer_tab as Customer_tab 
join Order_tab  as Order_tab 
on Order_tab.email= Customer_tab.email
```

Update depends on the database structure.
Maybe you can add some more detail about tables and the link between customer and order.

Comment: Well, only distantly like that

Comment: If is db structure complicated do in in several steps. Create tmp talbe with new customer ID and email adress  and compare this table with table with orders

Comment: This query has linked the accounts to the orders, it means I can see the clients infos in the order page.

UPDATE sales_flat_order as SFO INNER JOIN customer_entity as C on C.email = SFO.customer_email SET SFO.customer_id = C.entity_id WHERE SFO.customer_is_guest = 0

But when I open clients accounts > Orders tab, the orders are not there.